# How Can I concat two value on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
 <a href=" + ${legend.application_base_url} + ${legend.application_url} + ">
```

This is my error result `http://catsinfo.cats.com.kh/ + doconline/ +`

That I want just `http://catsinfo.cats.com.kh/doconline/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the extra spaces and useless `+` signs. `${}` already interpolates the values into a template literal.

```js
`<a href="${legend.application_base_url}${legend.application_url}">`
```